# Update a file variable (Active Storage)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activestorage

I'm using ActiveStorage (which is great !) to manage files in my app. An admin have to validate all the submits. So to solve that, I added a new column validated into the ActiveStorageBlob table. As I can define if the file is validated or not by the admin.

But my problem is that I cannot update this value. But I can ask the value of this variable.

```
def upd_val
  @photo = current_user.photo
  if @photo.validated?
    @photo.update(validated: true)
  else
    @photo.update(validated: false)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like that :

```
def upd_val
  @photo = current_user.photo
  @photo_id = @photo.id
  if @photo.validated?
    ActiveStorage::Blob.find(@photo_id).update(validated: true)
  else
    ActiveStorage::Blob.find(@photo_id).update(validated: false)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks @JacquesMesnet, that's exactly what I'm looking for !!